# Default Windows text to speech voice not working on applications

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, text-to-speech

The default text-to-speech voice is French on my PC, I want it to be English, so I opened the text to speech configuration and defined English as the default voice but when I use text to speech functionality in an application such as word, it is still using the french voice.. Can someone help me ? Any ideas, how can I force it to be English ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Word will use the language of your version of Office for its text-to-speech feature. If your version is French, it will speak French, English for the English version and so on.

To use a different language, you can download additional language packs, known as text to speech engines or TTS language engines.

To do this, download the Microsoft Speech Platform from the Microsoft Download Center and install it.

Then, download the TTS language engine you require (in this case, English) and install it following the instructions it provides.

Once installed, restart Office and the change should take affect.

Link to Microsoft Speech Platform - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24974

Direct Link to the English TTS Language Engine  - http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/redir/XT101843595.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA101825279

Comment: For those looking for other Languages, see the full list by expanding it under the 'Download additional TTS language engines' section of this page: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/using-the-speak-feature-with-multilingual-tts-HA101825279.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102066711

This answer should help with enabling TTS in English for Word. As for fixing the system-wide default, another answer may be required.